# Mock member variables

Tags: c#, moq

How do can I mock a member variables of a class?

It seems this `FooA()` is never called.

Note: I am beginner in moq (and rusty in C#) so please bear with me ;-)

> Unhandled Exception: Moq.MockVerificationException: The following
>   setups were not matched: IA a => a.FooA()

Here is the source code:

```
using Moq;

namespace TestMock
{
    interface IA {
        void FooA();
    }
    class A : IA {
        public void FooA() { }
    }

    class B {
        public void FooB() {
            a.FooA();
        }
        IA a = new A();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Arrange
            var mockA = new Mock<IA>();
            mockA.Setup(a => a.FooA());
            var mockB = new Mock<B>();

            // Act
            B b = new B();
            b.FooB();

            // Assert
            mockA.VerifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the `mockA` you create in your main method, instead the class `B` always creates a new instance of the class `A` by itself. So the method call you setup for `mockA` is indeed never made, which is why the verification fails.

Comment: That is because you create a new instance of `B` manually and do not use the mock. You would need to inject the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

`B` in its original form is tightly coupled to dependency `IA` which makes it difficult to mock when testing.

Refactor `B` to depend on `IA` via constructor injection. ([Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/))

```
class B {
    IA a;

    public B(IA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void FooB() {
        a.FooA();
    }
}
```

Now inject the mocked dependency in the test and verify behavior

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMoq() {
    // Arrange
    var mockA = new Mock<IA>();
    mockA.Setup(a => a.FooA());

    // Act
    B b = new B(mockA.Object);
    b.FooB();

    // Assert
    mockA.VerifyAll();
}
```